# Error: "Failed to create SipSession; network unavailable" when I want to start a new SIP session in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sip

I want to make a SIP call with Android. I know that the connection is ok. I tested it in X-Lite. But the createSipSession() does not execute. This is the error:

> Failed to create SipSession; network unavailable?

This is my code:

```
public SipManager mSipManager = null;
public SipProfile mSipProfile = null;
public SipAudioCall mCall = null;


public void onbtnLoginClicked(View v) {

    // Create SIP Manager
    if (mSipManager == null) {
        mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

    // Find EditText controls
    EditText txtId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtId);
    EditText txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    EditText txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    TextView lblError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblError);

    lblError.setText("No Errors Yet");

    String id = txtId.getText().toString();
    String username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
    String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

    try {

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username,id);
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("sip:rostamiani@sip2sip.info");
        builder.setPassword(password);
        mSipProfile = builder.build();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onbtnCallClicked(View v) {

    TextView lblError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblError);
    lblError.setText("No Errors Yet");

    try {
        mCall = mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile.getUriString(),"sip:3333@sip2sip.info",null,20);
        SipAudioCall.Listener mCallListener = new SipAudioCall.Listener();  // <---Error
    }
    catch (SipException e) {
        Log.e("SipService", e.getMessage());
        lblError.setText(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was changing the sip account, because it didn't support my country, and secondly I added a "sleep time" right after the login (10 seconds, but it could be 5).

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
```